# how to send data in javascript http Get request

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, puppet

I am trying to write postgre puppet AST query in java script/coffee script, but I am not able to figure out how to send data (curl -d) through a GET request in java/coffree scripts. Can anyone help?

```
curl -X GET http://puppetdb.com:8080/pdb/query/v4/reports -d 'query=["extract", ["hash", "end_time", "certname", "status", "noop", "metrics", "configuration_version", "environment"], ["and", ["=", "status", "failed"], ["and", ["=", "latest_report?",true]]]]'
```

Comment: You don't send data via GET. That's why it's GET. Use PUT or POST and send an HTTP body (JSON, form, xml, etc).

Comment: By don't I mean *shouldn't*. You can write your server to accept query params, but very bad practise and not at all RESTful.

Comment: no, the above request won't work with POST method, i did try that. server will return saying "POST method is not allowed on this request).

Comment: also I posted the curl request, from that its obvious GET method with sending data (curl -d) works just fine

Comment: Gotcha, I misunderstood and thought puppet was your own backend. In that case, if they built it that way (*slap!*) you're kinda stuck. From what I can see, that should work - maybe try sending it to a http://requestb.in and inspect the request?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this problem, can do this using query string
querystring = require('querystring')
    query='["extract", ["hash", "end_time", "certname", "status", "noop", "metrics", "configuration_version", "environment"], ["and", ["=", "status", "failed"], ["and", ["=", "latest_report?",true]]]]'
options =
        host: opts.host
        port: opts.port
        path: '/pdb/query/v4/nodes?' + querystring.stringify(query: query)